# Convert ASCII/Unicode text string to binary and reverse

Tags: bash, binary, ascii

I want to convert text string or numerical input to binary, for example

Input Text = hi all

Output = 011010000110100100100000011000010110110001101100

1 bit Text -> 8bit Binary

I found a Perl script that does the conversion from text to binary but doesn't do the opposite effectively (most of the time). I have manually checked every step and the error is at the `ciphertext=$(echo $ciphertext_bin | perl -lpe '$_=pack"B*",$_')` step. Is there an error or there is a better way>

```
#!/bin/bash

##Message
#Ask for Input 
echo -n "Enter your message:"
read plaintext

#ASCII to Binary Conversion
plaintext_bin=$(echo "$plaintext" | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"')

#Count chars
plaintext_size=${#plaintext}
plaintext_bin_size=${#plaintext_bin}

##One Time Pad
#Generate Random Sequence
key=$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c $plaintext_size;)
echo key is $key

#ASCII to Binary Conversion
key_bin=$(echo $key | perl -lpe '$_=unpack"B*"')

##CipherText
# plaintext_bin -||XOR||- key_bin
for ((i=0; i < $plaintext_bin_size; i++)); do      
    byte=$(( ${plaintext_bin:i:1} ^ ${key_bin:i:1} ))
    ciphertext_bin=$ciphertext_bin$byte
done

ciphertext=$(echo $ciphertext_bin | perl -lpe '$_=pack"B*",$_')

echo ciphertext is $ciphertext
```

Comment: Note well that the ciphertext produced by an approach such as yours must be considered *binary* data. Interpreted according to ASCII, it is reasonably likely to contain non-printing control characters, and it may contain the NUL character.

Comment: I'd start by doing the whole thing in perl.

Comment: You mean _1 **byte** text → 8 bit binary_, right?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92448/353114). With `chr()` and `ord()` in place, you can easily convert both ways using built-in arithmetics in Bash.